# Generate SVG in C++

Tags: c++, svg

Is it possible in C++ to create SVG file by just writing an SVG text file? In web development (PHP and JS in mind) one can manipulate SVG as other DOM elements (unless I am mistaken). However, I want to just create an SVG in that web style (no reading, parsing,...). Or is it better to just download a library?

I want to compare speeds of tasks (calculating and plotting a graph) with MatLab with which we work at school and I need a simple solution to graphical output.

Comment: Yes, you can certainly create an SVG file as a simple ASCII text file. Just save it as `filename.svg`. I have segments of the SVG code stored in a SQL database and I write it out with variables for `x` and `y` and for `text` strings. Works great.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would suggest is to design your graphics using a vector graphics editor like Inkscape (free).

Then you can open the resulting SVG file in your favorite text editor and save snippets of the file as strings to insert into your own file:
For example, here is a part of a file for drawing a circle:

```
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <circle 
       style="opacity:0.1;fill:#008000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.26458332;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="path10"
       cx="43.534008"
       cy="32.312469"
       r="18.520834" />    
  </g>
```

I would also get rid of extraneous information, such as the `inkscape:label` and `inkscape:groupmode` which you don't need, and especially the `id=` since you want to reuse the code. Then save pieces of this in static strings (or better in a array or structure):

```cpp
    const string circleS0 = "<g id=\"circle1\"><circle style=\"opacity:0.1;fill:#008000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.26458332;stroke-opacity:1\" id=\"path10\" cx=\"";
    const string circleS1 = "\" cy=\"";
    const string circleS2 = "\"  r=\"";
    const string circleS3 = "\" /> </g>";
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** SVG format *requires* a lot of double-quotes which unfortunately have to be escaped in C++ (as I did above).

Now you create some variables that contain the things that make this a unique circle that you can draw where you want:

```cpp
    string circleX = "43.534008";
    string circleY = "32.312469";
    string circleR = "18.520834";
```

Finally, you need to output all the pieces in order, but I'll leave that to your C++ skills.

This example might seem overwhelming without a library, but I did it for creating electrical cable assembly drawings and text grids (Bills of Materials) and it was not hard at all. I even include the customer's logo in the title block of the drawings thanks to embedded graphics.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get what you're asking. Of course you could write an SVG file using c++, but without library support you would have to make sure you're following the right (xml-like) structure.

If you want to make your life a lot easier, use SVG++ (http://svgpp.org/)..

Comment: I am looking mostly for a solution without library support because of speed and simplicity. The XML strructure should not be a problem, I just create a "template" and then calculate values with C++ and put them in the template. (Glue strings of text together to form and SVG file.)

Comment: @MStarha *I am looking mostly for a solution without library support because of speed and simplicity* -- With all due respect, that makes very little sense.  Persons responsible for writing such libraries are not novices.   You would expect them to put every effort in speed and efficiency, and have a public interface that is easy for the user of the library to utilize.  Using a library makes it *easier* for the end-programmer, not more difficult.

Comment: I do not doubt that. By speed I meant that glueing strings together is faster than going through libraries. All in all in this case the difference is most likely negligible. And by simplicity I meant, everyone that looks at the code does not need to understand the library because you just "glue" together parts of SVG contained as text.